# Why does my password generator written in JavaScript often return passwords with repeating characters?

Tags: javascript, math, random, password-generator

I've written a JavaScript class with four static variables containing the different kinds of characters the final password may include. The class contains four getter functions which return a random character from these four variables. In a separate function I try to create the password. Unfortunately the final password does not seem to contain wholly random characters. Often same characters are repeated.

I had a closer look at my random-function but it seems to be fine. I hope you have an idea why the passwords end up being so similar e.g. AAAh^8 or bSS+5S

```
class Password{
    
    static lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static upperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    static numbers   = "0123456789";
    static symbols   = "!@#$%^&*()_+~\\`|}{[]:;?><,./-=";

    length = document.getElementById("passwordLength").value;

    getKey = [this.upperCase, this.lowerCase, this.num, this.symbol]

    get upperCase(){
        return Password.upperCase[Math.floor(Math.random() * Password.upperCase.length)]
        }
    get lowerCase(){
        return Password.lowerCase[Math.floor(Math.random() * Password.lowerCase.length)]
    }
    get num(){
        return Password.numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * Password.numbers.length)]
    }
    get symbol(){
        return Password.symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * Password.symbols.length)]
    }
    password = ""
}

function createPassword(){
    const newPass = new Password;
     
    for (var i=0; i<newPass.length; i++){
        key = newPass.getKey[Math.floor(Math.random() * newPass.getKey.length)]
        newPass.password += key
        console.log("Random Key Run " + i + ": " + key)
    }
    console.log("Final Password: " + newPass.password)
}
createPassword()
```

Comment: `console.log(getKey)`…! Your functions are *getters*. `this.upperCase` returns a *value*, not the function itself.

Comment: [How to debug small programs... StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) After debugging you should create a [mcve] without randomness.

Comment: I suggest using a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/) when you don't understand why code isn't behaving as expected. More here: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: IOW what @deceze is saying is `getKey = [this.upperCase, this.lowerCase, this.num, this.symbol]` essentially "pre-selects" the 4 different characters you can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @deceze says, you're essentially pre-selecting your 4 different characters in the `getKey` initializer.

You'll probably have a better time if you're less fancy with getters, e.g.

```
function pick(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

class PasswordGenerator {
  static lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  static upperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  static numbers = "0123456789";
  static symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_+~\\`|}{[]:;?><,./-=";
  static classes = [
    PasswordGenerator.lowerCase,
    PasswordGenerator.upperCase,
    PasswordGenerator.numbers,
    PasswordGenerator.symbols,
  ];

  getChar() {
    const cls = pick(PasswordGenerator.classes);
    return pick(cls);
  }
}

function createPassword() {
  const generator = new PasswordGenerator();
  let password = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    const key = generator.getChar();
    password += key;
    console.log(`Random Key Run ${i}: ${key}`);
  }
  console.log("Final Password: " + password);
}

createPassword();
```

I also took the liberty of moving stuff that shouldn't necessarily be `Password` state out of the `PasswordGenerator` class.

Comment: Thank you so much for your code suggestion. It took me little while to understand what you did in the getChar function but it definitely broadened my horizon on how to work with arrays. Such an elegant solution! <3